# Approximate rational dependence

Tags: vector-spaces, irrational-numbers

After seeing question [Why is $10\frac{\exp(\pi)-\log 3}{\log 2}$ almost an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146568/why-is-10-frac-exp-pi-log-3-log-2-almost-an-integer) I wonder if there is an algorithm that can find approximate rational dependence?! I pick any irrational numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $ \delta$ and the task is to find successively good approximations for rational numbers $q_i$ in

$q_1\alpha+q_2\beta+q_3\gamma+q_4\delta\approx0$

Basically it's like continued fraction approximations, but for more irrational numbers.

What is such an algorithm called?

Comment: I think the LLL-algorithm of Lenstra, Lenstra, Lovasz does something like this

Comment: @Cocopuffs: Can this algorithm handle rational numbers or is it integer only?

Comment: I doubt there's any optimality for rational numbers, although you can certainly divide by a common denominator.  I'm not sure exactly how this would work. The problem as given I don't fully understand either, as you can obviously take $q_1 = ... = q_4 = 0$, but I'm sure you want to exclude that.

Comment: like Cocopuffs and Gerry(+1) explained you may use LLL and PSLQ. This was tried [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/approximation-of-e-using-pi-and-phi/108520#108520) (to get better approximations you need only to increase the precision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an integer relation algorithm. In addition to LLL mentioned in the comments, there's also PSLQ and others. The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) on integer relation algorithms will get you started on understanding these algorithms.